# switching alignment

Tags: equations, align, arrays, split

I'm new to Latex and its environments such as `split` and `align` and I'm trying to change the alignment of an equation in a customized manner. I have a set of equations *similar* to what you can see in the picture below. My goal is to shift the last line's equal sign to where it is indicated by the arrow while keeping the alignment of the second line untouched.

[image]

I need to do this since my actual equation is pretty long and I'm trying to fit it in one slide. I appreciate your ideas.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rough code as you didn't provide a MWE. You can use `aligned` inside of `align`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}_{1}[q]&=\begin{aligned}[t]
\mathcal{H}[q(\theta)] &=-\int q(\theta) \ln q(\theta) d \theta \\
&=-\int \prod_{i} q\left(\theta_{i}\right)\left[\sum_{j} \ln q\left(\theta_{j}\right)\right] \prod_{l} d \theta_{l} 
\end{aligned}\\ 
&=-\sum_{i} \int q\left(\theta_{i}\right) \ln q\left(\theta_{i}\right) d \theta_{i} 
\end{align*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

In my eyes, though, it is more readable to put each `=` on its own line:

```
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}_{1}[q]&=\mathcal{H}[q(\theta)] \\
&=-\int q(\theta) \ln q(\theta) d \theta \\
&=-\int \prod_{i} q\left(\theta_{i}\right)\left[\sum_{j} \ln q\left(\theta_{j}\right)\right] \prod_{l} d \theta_{l} \\ 
&=-\sum_{i} \int q\left(\theta_{i}\right) \ln q\left(\theta_{i}\right) d \theta_{i} 
\end{align*}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Why not this simpler layout?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}_{1}[q]&=\mathcal{H}[q(\theta)] =-\int q(\theta) \ln q(\theta) d \theta \\
&=-\int \prod_{i} q\left(\theta_{i}\right)\Bigl[\sum_{j} \ln q\left(\theta_{j}\right)\Bigr] \prod_{l} d \theta_{l}\\
&=-\sum_{i} \int q\left(\theta_{i}\right) \ln q\left(\theta_{i}\right) d \theta_{i}
\end{align*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: basically, my equation is long that I cannot fit it in one slide. So I was thinking of a neat way to do it and that was one of the options. I agree that it's not readable as before though.